# Can't initialize Dozer 5.3.2

Tags: java, dozer

Updated Dozer to 5.3.2. when dozer is trying to initialize prints this message infinity times.
How to fix this problem?

> |11:06:25| INFO|zer.DozerInitializer|      | - Initializing Dozer.
>   Version: 5.3.2, Thread Name: main |11:06:25|
>   INFO|zer.DozerInitializer|      | - Initializing Dozer. Version:
>   5.3.2, Thread Name: main |11:06:25| INFO|zer.DozerInitializer|      | - Initializing Dozer. Version: 5.3.2, Thread Name: main

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using the same version, and have never seen this problem. I would set the log level for dozer to DEBUG to see what he's actually trying to do when initializing.